# Flutter + Firebase Functions and Hosting recommended folder structure

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, directory-structure

As my project grows I'm wanting to setup an elegant and scalable folder structure but I'm unsure what the best practices are.

My project includes a

- Flutter app
- Firebase Functions
- Firebase Hosting with a static landing page and will soon have 2 Angular apps

My current structure is this:

```
Root flutter app
 |
 +-- README.md
 +-- package.json (with flutter build commands)
 +-- Flutter code (lib, test assets etc)
 |
 +-- Firebase
 |   |
 |   +-- package.json (with firebase build commands)
 |   +-- Functions
 |   |   |
 |   |   +-- src (functions code)
 |   |   |
 |   +-- Firestore
 |   |   |
 |   |   +-- firestore.rules
 |   |   +-- firestore.indexes
```

Should my root directory look like this:

```
- Flutter
- Firebase (Functions, hosting, firestore)
```

Or something more like this:

```
- Flutter
- Functions
- Hosting (App1, App2, Static landing etc)
- Firestore
```

But then where is best to keep build files and deploy scripts for each site/service/app?

I haven't implemented CI/CD yet, **but I plan to implement it soon**, so I'd probably want to take that into consideration.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

*The question is 4 years old and OP obviously had found his answers, but anyway.*

We don't need an additional folder for Firestore, as all code that is related to Firestore is a regular Dart/Flutter code that resides in the `lib` folder.

We don't need an additional folder for Hosting, as everything related to hosting is autogenerated and resides in the `build/web` folder.

We only need an additional folder for Firebase Functions.

So, just add the `functions` folder to the root of your project:

```
functions \
          index.js
lib \
    main.dart
...
pubspec.yaml
```